# how to build customize libcurl to support HTTP / HTTPS protocol only

Tags: c++, visual-c++, curl, libcurl

I am using libcurl only to make HTTP / HTTPS request. I have downloaded the source and built as a static library.

MY final executable has increased in size a bit. I am trying to trim down my executable exe as I have other restriction.

During analysis i observed the libcurl is built with support for many protocols including HTTP. however my specific use is HTTP/HTTPS.

Is there a way where i can define compilation flag to disable other protocols when building libcurl?

Thank you for reading the post!!!

Comment: Try `./configure --disable-ftp --disable-file --...`, for all protocols you don't want.

Comment: Forgot to mention:
i am trying to get the library in WIN env and i am building on VC++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

```
    Disabling Specific Protocols in Win32 builds
   --------------------------------------------

   The configure utility, unfortunately, is not available for the Windows
   environment, therefore, you cannot use the various disable-protocol
   options of the configure utility on this platform.

   However, you can use the following defines to disable specific
   protocols:

   HTTP_ONLY             disables all protocols except HTTP
   CURL_DISABLE_FTP      disables FTP
   CURL_DISABLE_LDAP     disables LDAP
   CURL_DISABLE_TELNET   disables TELNET
   CURL_DISABLE_DICT     disables DICT
   CURL_DISABLE_FILE     disables FILE
   CURL_DISABLE_TFTP     disables TFTP
   CURL_DISABLE_HTTP     disables HTTP

   If you want to set any of these defines you have the following
   possibilities:

   - Modify lib/config-win32.h
   - Modify lib/curl_setup.h
   - Modify lib/Makefile.vc6
   - Add defines to Project/Settings/C/C++/General/Preprocessor Definitions
     in the vc6libcurl.dsw/vc6libcurl.dsp Visual C++ 6 IDE project.
```