# Http request in C++ using libcurl: reduce binary size, static linking

Tags: c++, static-libraries, libcurl

As I can see, there are a lot of C++ apis to support HTTP (cpp-netlib, boost, etc) but I would like to use libcurl.
All I want to do is to support HTTP (cookies included). How can I statically link the essential libraries needed? I'm on Windows 7 x86, I've read [this](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) without success: the HTTP_ONLY define is the right way to achieve my goal? And how to statically link the library?
Thank you!

IDE and compiler: MVC++

**EDIT 1**:
I've got problems from the beginning (building): I need to compile libcurl to reduce the size and then link it in statically. I didn't understood the "install" documentation in the help page of libcurl, particularly the part about HTTP_ONLY define and the compilation flags. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to build customize libcurl to support HTTP / HTTPS protocol only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251101/how-to-build-customize-libcurl-to-support-http-https-protocol-only)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Best answer regards the link I've just posted. I've got building problems!

Comment: If you have specific problems with building, then you'd better post WHAT those problems are (in your question, not as a comment, ideally).