# How to add size reducing options to cUrl's Makefile.vc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, static-libraries

Currently I build static cUrl with command:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc MACHINE=x64 mode=static RTLIBCFG=static DEBUG=no ENABLE_IDN=no ENABLE_IPV6=no
```

cUrl documentation says there are 4 places to configure its building, one of these places is `winbuild\Makefile.vc`. I want to modify this file to add some define options, cited in an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251101/how-to-build-customize-libcurl-to-support-http-https-protocol-only) post, e.g.:

> HTTP_ONLY             disables all protocols except HTTP
> CURL_DISABLE_FTP      disables FTP
> CURL_DISABLE_LDAP     disables LDAP
> CURL_DISABLE_TELNET   disables TELNET
> CURL_DISABLE_DICT     disables DICT
> CURL_DISABLE_FILE     disables FILE
> CURL_DISABLE_TFTP     disables TFTP
> CURL_DISABLE_HTTP     disables HTTP

Also, I want to add some options from [documentation](https://curl.se/docs/install.html), like:

```
--disable-alt-svc (HTTP Alt-Svc)
--disable-ares (the C-ARES DNS library)
--disable-cookies (HTTP cookies)
--disable-crypto-auth (cryptographic authentication)
--disable-dateparse (date parsing for time conditionals)
```